# get integer from dictionary, incompatible types

Tags: java, android

How do I get integer from the dictionary? Thanks for help !

```
Hashtable<Integer, Integer> groupsPostId = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();
groupsPostId.put(1, 100);

Integer postId = groupsPostId.get(1);

Error: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Integer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting :

```
Integer postId = (Integer) groupsPostId.get(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the synchronized class "Hashtable" with an unsynchronized one such as "HashMap". Nobody doesn't use Hashtable since java 1.5 I think.
Also, your snippet doesn't make any problem when I put its in my IDE